# Materials have no color when put in unity

Tags: materials, unity

So I am just adding a sphere that has just 1 material to unity and when I add it to the asset folder there's no material, When I extract material its just a blank material. I have tried EVERYTHING what am I doing wrong? (using blender 2.8)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57531/599

Answer (score 1):

you have to bake the whole material. unity otherwise you do not recognize the materials of blender. 
look at this exhaustive [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131622/how-bake-cycles-material-to-pbr-texture-in-2-80/131628#131628) to my question that is similar to yours